# Appind only once and replace when changed

Tags: jquery, css, append

Here is what I wanna do. Create diffrent contents with input and upload and finally add all the content together. I am using jQuery to append the content to my Modal for a preview. First had the problem that it appended multiple times, solved that with one("click"...

But when I am editing my content in the Editor it should recognize it and change the content. Can I add a change.() or something? Or is there a custom function already for that kind of purpose.

```
function appendAll($param){
        var test = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();            

        $($param).append(test);

    }

    $("#preview").one("click", function() {
        $("#preview").change(appendAll('.modal-body'));

    });
```

Comment: its `$("#preview").on("click", function() {`

Comment: @Varun `.one( event, handler )` is valid. It binds a handler to and element/object for a single event.

Comment: .one only declares that it should do it once. When I use .on I have the problem that it will add the content over and over again. But in the preview the users should only see it once, obviously. They are clicking the preview button like 5-10 times.

Comment: @Isengo it's hard to tell what the expected user work flow is and how you have your user interface setup with the limited amount of code/information in your post. Could you please add more details about how the user interacts with your app and additional code like the elements they're expected to interact with etc.

Comment: @Isengo you can use the `.on` and clear the `.modal-body` every time you append the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<div class='modal-body'>
   <span class='tinyMCE_content'></span>
</div>

function appendAll($param){
        var test = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
        $($param).html(test);
    }

    $("#preview").on("click", function() {
        $("#preview").change(appendAll('.modal-body span.tinyMCE_content'));

    });
```

Comment: this kinda works since it gives out the tags instead of styling them.

Comment: other than content from tinyMCE, what else you have inside `.modal-body`?

Comment: using .html instead of .text works. This will come soon. It will be Images and links, and more Editor contents. I guess I have to use an array and go throw it with a foreach e.g.

Comment: you could create a span inside `.modal-body` and target that span to place this content, which would be lot cleaner, I suppose.